# Is $4k$ the best bound to ensure that a graph with $d(G)\ge 4k$ has a bipartite subgraph $H$ with $\delta(H)\ge k$?

Tags: graph-theory

It's known (and it's a nice exercise in Diestel's book) that every graph $G$ with $d(G)\ge 4k$ (where $d(G)$ is the average degree of $G$) has a bipartite subgraph $H$ with minimum degree $\delta(H)\ge k$.

My question is: Is $4k$ the best bound known?